# ORA-01407: cannot update ("schema"."UTILISATEUR"."ID_PERSONNE") to NULL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can you pleas help me ?
I have this issue ORA-01407: cannot update ("schema"."UTILISATEUR"."ID_PERSONNE") to NULL.

*** But I checked and "schema"."UTILISATEUR"."ID_PERSONNE" is not null !!
Every record is filled.

Below the query :

```
UPDATE schema.utilisateur
  SET schema.utilisateur.ID_Personne = (select testtable.New_ID_Personne
                                        from testtable
                                        where TESTTABLE.Login = schema.utilisateur.Login
                                          and testtable.New_id_personne is not null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to there being `login`s in the `schema.utilisateur` table that aren't present in `testtable`, meaning the corresponding `new_id_personne` will be null. You need to add a `where` clause to your `update` statement to make sure that you're only updating rows that exist in `testtable`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE schema.utilisateur su
  SET su.ID_Personne = (select testtable.New_ID_Personne
                        from   testtable tt1
                        where  tt1.Login = su.Login
                        and    tt1.New_id_personne is not null)
where exists (select null
              from   testtable tt2
              where  tt2.Login = su.Login
              and    tt2.New_id_personne is not null);
```

or you could convert it into a `merge` statement, e.g.:

```
merge into schema.utilisateur tgt
  using (select testtable.New_ID_Personne
         from   testtable tt
         where  tt1.New_id_personne is not null) src
  on (tgt.login = src.login)
when matched then
update set tgt.id_personne = src.new_id_personne;
```

Comment: Thanks you.
Indeed, logins in the schema.utilisateur table that aren't present in testtable, meaning the corresponding new_id_personne will be null.

I was thinking that update query will let the id_person unchanged if it did not find the login and follow the query.